# Remove empty dictionary(nested) from list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
data = [
    {
        "2022": [
            {
                "Title": "Title"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Title 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2023": []
    },
    {
        "2024": []
    }
]
```

Now I want to remove 2023 and 2024 because it do not have any value.
Solution in python :

```
for el in data:
    for dict in el.values():
        if len(dict) == 0:
            data.remove(el)
```

Similar Solution in JS :

```
data = data.filter(item=>Object.values(item)[0].length > 0)
```

What i want is similar to js. (I am not an expert in python)

Comment: What's the point of having 1 element dictionaries?

Comment: `data = [item for item in data if next(iter(item.values()))]`

Comment: @matszwecja its just a reference. in real data coming from json file.

Comment: I mean the outer ones contained in `data`. Will they ever contain anything else than a single year key?

Comment: @matszwecja we are using  `list.append()` to connate multiple json file. there are more process goes on till we reach this point. here JSON object are not manual driven.

Comment: How it was created is kinda irrelevant, the outer list is completely unecessary from the looks of it.

Comment: @matszwecja its a server response with `{"status":200,"data":[...{}]}` , data is being concated.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in one line:

```
data = [
    {
        "2022": [
            {
                "Title": "Title"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Title 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2023": []
    },
    {
        "2024": []
    }
]

# using list comprehension
result = [{k: v} for el in data for k, v in el.items() if len(v) > 0]
print(f"list comprehension way: {result}")
# or you are a fan of Functional programming
data = filter(lambda x: len(list(x.values())[0]) > 0, data)
# note that filter function returns a filter object, a.k.a. iterator,
# which cannot be accessed by using `plain print` but using `for loop`
for i in data:
    print(i)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
list comprehension way: [{'2022': [{'Title': 'Title'}, {'Title': 'Title 2'}]}]
{'2022': [{'Title': 'Title'}, {'Title': 'Title 2'}]}
<filter object at 0x103804050>
```

Comment: `data = list(filter(lambda x: len(list(x.values())[0]) > 0, data))`
This will remove filter object

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH Yes. But using iterator will have better performance if you intend to use it in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

#### A better way:

```
data = [ item  for item in data if list(item.values())[0] ]
```

Output:

```
[{'2022': [{'Title': 'Title'}, {'Title': 'Title 2'}]}]
```

#### Or:

```
data = [ item  for item in data for key in item.keys() if item[key] != [] ]
```

Output:

```
[{'2022': [{'Title': 'Title'}, {'Title': 'Title 2'}]}]
```